# Perspective correct texture mapping; z distance calculation might be wrong

Tags: c++, rasterizing, zbuffer

I'm making a software rasterizer, and I've run into a bit of a snag: I can't seem to get perspective-correct texture mapping to work.

My algorithm is to first sort the coordinates to plot by `y`. This returns a highest, lowest and center point. I then walk across the scanlines using the delta's:

```
// ordering by y is put here

order[0] = &a_Triangle.p[v_order[0]];
order[1] = &a_Triangle.p[v_order[1]];
order[2] = &a_Triangle.p[v_order[2]];

float height1, height2, height3;

height1 = (float)((int)(order[2]->y + 1) - (int)(order[0]->y));
height2 = (float)((int)(order[1]->y + 1) - (int)(order[0]->y));
height3 = (float)((int)(order[2]->y + 1) - (int)(order[1]->y));

// x 

float x_start, x_end;
float x[3];
float x_delta[3];

x_delta[0] = (order[2]->x - order[0]->x) / height1;
x_delta[1] = (order[1]->x - order[0]->x) / height2;
x_delta[2] = (order[2]->x - order[1]->x) / height3;

x[0] = order[0]->x;
x[1] = order[0]->x;
x[2] = order[1]->x;
```

And then we render from `order[0]->y` to `order[2]->y`, increasing the `x_start` and `x_end` by a delta. When rendering the top part, the delta's are `x_delta[0]` and `x_delta[1]`. When rendering the bottom part, the delta's are `x_delta[0]` and `x_delta[2]`. Then we linearly interpolate between x_start and x_end on our scanline. UV coordinates are interpolated in the same way, ordered by y, starting at begin and end, to which delta's are applied each step.

This works fine except when I try to do perspective correct UV mapping. The basic algorithm is to take `UV/z` and `1/z` for each vertex and interpolate between them. For each pixel, the UV coordinate becomes `UV_current * z_current`. However, this is the result:

[image]

The inversed part tells you where the delta's are flipped. As you can see, the two triangles both seem to be going towards different points in the horizon.

Here's what I use to calculate the Z at a point in space:

```
float GetZToPoint(Vec3 a_Point)
{
    Vec3 projected = m_Rotation * (a_Point - m_Position);

    // #define FOV_ANGLE 60.f
    // static const float FOCAL_LENGTH = 1 / tanf(_RadToDeg(FOV_ANGLE) / 2);
    // static const float DEPTH = HALFHEIGHT * FOCAL_LENGTH; 
    float zcamera = DEPTH / projected.z;

    return zcamera;
}
```

Am I right, is it a z buffer issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ZBuffer has nothing to do with it.

THe ZBuffer is only useful when triangles are overlapping and you want to make sure that they are drawn correctly (e.g. correctly ordered in the Z). The ZBuffer will, for every pixel of the triangle, determine if a previously placed pixel is nearer to the camera, and if so, not draw the pixel of your triangle.

Since you are drawing 2 triangles which don't overlap, this can not be the issue.

I've made a software rasterizer in fixed point once (for a mobile phone), but I don't have the sources on my laptop. So let me check tonight, how I did it. In essence what you've got is not bad! A thing like this could be caused by a very small error

General tips in debugging this is to have a few test triangles (slope left-side, slope right-side, 90 degree angles, etc etc) and step through it with the debugger and see how your logic deals with the cases.

EDIT:

peudocode of my rasterizer (only U, V and Z are taken into account...  if you also want to do gouraud you also have to do everything for R G and B similar as to what you are doing for U and V and Z:

The idea is that a triangle can be broken down in 2 parts. The top part and the bottom part. The top is from y[0] to y[1]   and the bottom part is from y[1] to y[2]. For both sets you need to calculate the step variables with which you are interpolating. The below example shows you how to do the top part. If needed I can supply the bottom part too.

Please note that I do already calculate the needed interpolation offsets for the bottom part in the below 'pseudocode' fragment

- first order the coords(x,y,z,u,v) in the order so that coord[0].y < coord[1].y < coord[2].y
- next check if any 2 sets of coordinates are identical (only check x and y). If so don't draw
- exception: does the triangle have a flat top? if so, the first slope will be infinite
- exception2: does the triangle have a flat bottom (yes triangles can have these too ;^)  ) then the last slope too will be infinite
- calculate 2 slopes (left side and right side)
  leftDeltaX = (x[1] - x[0]) / (y[1]-y[0]) and rightDeltaX = (x[2] - x[0]) / (y[2]-y[0])
- the second part of the triangle is calculated dependent on: if the left side of the triangle is now really on the leftside (or needs swapping)

code fragment:

```
 if (leftDeltaX < rightDeltaX)
 {
      leftDeltaX2 = (x[2]-x[1]) / (y[2]-y[1])
      rightDeltaX2 = rightDeltaX
      leftDeltaU = (u[1]-u[0]) / (y[1]-y[0]) //for texture mapping
      leftDeltaU2 = (u[2]-u[1]) / (y[2]-y[1])
      leftDeltaV = (v[1]-v[0]) / (y[1]-y[0]) //for texture mapping
      leftDeltaV2 = (v[2]-v[1]) / (y[2]-y[1])
      leftDeltaZ = (z[1]-z[0]) / (y[1]-y[0]) //for texture mapping
      leftDeltaZ2 = (z[2]-z[1]) / (y[2]-y[1])
 }
 else
 {
      swap(leftDeltaX, rightDeltaX);
      leftDeltaX2 = leftDeltaX;
      rightDeltaX2 = (x[2]-x[1]) / (y[2]-y[1])
      leftDeltaU = (u[2]-u[0]) / (y[2]-y[0]) //for texture mapping
      leftDeltaU2 = leftDeltaU
      leftDeltaV = (v[2]-v[0]) / (y[2]-y[0]) //for texture mapping
      leftDeltaV2 = leftDeltaV
      leftDeltaZ = (z[2]-z[0]) / (y[2]-y[0]) //for texture mapping
      leftDeltaZ2 = leftDeltaZ
  }
```

- set the currentLeftX and currentRightX both on x[0]
- set currentLeftU on leftDeltaU, currentLeftV on leftDeltaV and currentLeftZ on leftDeltaZ
- calc start and endpoint for first Y range:  startY = ceil(y[0]); endY = ceil(y[1])
- prestep x,u,v and z for the fractional part of y for subpixel accuracy (I guess this is also needed for floats)
  For my fixedpoint algorithms this was needed to make the lines and textures give the illusion of moving in much finer steps then the resolution of the display)
- calculate where x should be at y[1]:   halfwayX = (x[2]-x[0]) * (y[1]-y[0]) / (y[2]-y[0]) + x[0]
  and same for U and V and z:   halfwayU = (u[2]-u[0]) * (y[1]-y[0]) / (y[2]-y[0]) + u[0]
- and using the halfwayX calculate the stepper for the U and V and z:
  if(halfwayX - x[1] == 0){ slopeU=0, slopeV=0, slopeZ=0 } else { slopeU = (halfwayU - U[1]) / (halfwayX - x[1])}  //(and same for v and z)
- do clipping for the Y top  (so calculate where we are going to start to draw in case the top of the triangle is off screen (or off the clipping rectangle))
- for y=startY; y < endY; y++)
  {

  - is Y past bottom of screen?   stop rendering!
  - calc startX and endX for the first horizontal line
    leftCurX = ceil(startx);  leftCurY = ceil(endy);
  - clip the line to be drawn to the left horizontal border of the screen (or clipping region)
  - prepare a pointer to the destination buffer (doing it through array indexes everytime is too slow)
    unsigned int *buf = destbuf + (y*pitch) + startX;   (unsigned int in case you are doing 24bit or 32 bits rendering)
    also prepare your ZBuffer pointer here (if you are using this)
  - for(x=startX; x < endX; x++)
    {

    - now for perspective texture mapping (using no bilineair interpolation you do the following):

code fragment:

```
         float tv = startV / startZ
         float tu = startU / startZ;
         tv %= texturePitch;  //make sure the texture coordinates stay on the texture if they are too wide/high
         tu %= texturePitch;  //I'm assuming square textures here. With fixed point you could have used &=
         unsigned int *textPtr = textureBuf+tu + (tv*texturePitch);   //in case of fixedpoints one could have shifted the tv. Now we have to multiply everytime. 
         int destColTm = *(textPtr);  //this is the color (if we only use texture mapping)  we'll be needing for the pixel
```

- dummy line

  - dummy line

    - dummy line
    - optional: check the zbuffer if the previously plotted pixel at this coordinate is higher or lower then ours.
    - plot the pixel
    - startZ += slopeZ; startU+=slopeU; startV += slopeV;    //update all interpolators
  - } end of x loop
  - leftCurX+= leftDeltaX; rightCurX += rightDeltaX; leftCurU+= rightDeltaU; leftCurV += rightDeltaV; leftCurZ += rightDeltaZ;  //update Y interpolators
- } end of y loop

  //this is the end of the first part. We now have drawn half the triangle. from the top, to the middle Y coordinate.
  // we now basically do the exact same thing but now for the bottom half of the triangle (using the other set of interpolators)

sorry about the 'dummy lines'.. they were needed to get the markdown codes in sync. (took me a while to get everything sort off looking as intended)

let me know if this helps you solve the problem you are facing!

Comment: Another tip for debugging, compute each texture point using the old-fashioned, non-incremental U and V coordinates for each pixel and compare to the incremental values calculated by your algorithm (allowing for some slop due to roundoff error).

Comment: Wow ... thats an answer and a half! :D

Comment: goz: now just hope it's useful since he probably has most of this code already in place judging by the picture. I'm thinking that probably he miscalculated one of the interpolation values. But hopefully if he lays his algorithm next to mine he can find out which one it is ;^)

Comment: Awesome answer! I actually solved the problem I had within minutes of assigning a bounty. :S But it's still quite strange, I have to divide the u and v by 1/z and multiply by 1/z to get the correct uv coordinates. However, I had abandoned my render method in favor of a more traditional "draw a box around triangle, determine min and max x for every slope", but your code should help fix my crappy code!

Comment: @knight666: judging by the picture and your explanation you already were really far. Sometimes it is a small division or other stupid thing which ruins the entire rendering, and it's difficult to track down. But it's soooo rewarding to get finally right ;^)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I can help with your question, but one of the best books on software rendering that I had read at the time is available online [Graphics Programming Black Book](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1698.asp) by Michael Abrash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interpolating `1/z`, you need to multiply `UV/z` by `z`, not `1/z`. Assuming you have this:

`UV = UV_current * z_current`

and `z_current` is interpolating `1/z`, you should change it to:

`UV = UV_current / z_current`

And then you might want to rename `z_current` to something like `one_over_z_current`.

Comment: It's probably a speed up trick: He needs to divide by z. But since multiplication is faster than division, he multiplies by 1/z.

Comment: You can't avoid a divide with perspective correct texture mapping. You can approximate it over a spam of pixels, but you can't eliminate it. Assuming you want something that looks correct.